# Selenium: Error comes using "if" to decide whether an element exists or not

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am sorry that if I ask a duplicate/stupid questions. I am confused with how to decide if an element exists. Errors:"Could not locate the id "smc"" will pop up if you run the following code.

```
if driver.find_element_by_id("smc"):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

The following code will be work:

```
try:
    verification = driver.find_element_by_id("smc")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No exits")
```

After I log in the page, it will enter one of the following options. Want to go the next step accordingly if one of the page has the "its own element".

```
1.1 page 1 
-How to verify: driver.find_element_by_id("smc")
-Next step: func1()
1.2. page 2 
-How to verify: driver.find_element_by_id("editPage")
-Next step: print("You need retry later") and exit the code
1.3. page 3
-How to verify: driver.find_element_by_id("cas2_ilecell")
-Next step: func2()
```

How do I complete my task? As I try to use "if" and it could not work....

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why cant you use the try-except block that you were using in your own example?

Comment: Put your `func()` call in your `try` block?

Comment: Actually this is not possible to the fullest extent in selenium, Even if you use `find_elements`, it would still wait for the given implicit wait. But when we inquire a status of the element, it must immediately needs to tell us whether it exist or not. Use WATIR(wrapper for Ruby Selenium Binding) where you could find such a good facility. you can simply write `b.element(id: 'something').exists?` or `b.element(id: 'something').present?` to check whether element exist or visible respectively.

Comment: @Rajagopalan, Do you mean this one https://github.com/watir/watir ？

Comment: Yes, but please refer here `http://watir.com/guides/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote the solution itself in your question. WebDriver throws `NoSuchElementException` if it is not able to find the element with the given locator and you need to handle it using try-except if you want your code to go to to an alternate path.

Other option you can use, if you don't want to handle exceptions is `driver.find_elements`. It returns a list of elements matching a locator and an empty list if it couldn't find any. So you will do something like -

```
count = len(driver.find_elements_by_id('some_id'))
if count == 0:
   //element was not found.. do something else instead
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
if driver.find_element_by_id("smc")
```

with

```
if driver.find_elements_by_id("smc")
```

Comment: The second statement would be waiting for given implicit wait(atleast for one element), but checking the status of the element must immediately tells the user whether it exists or not.

Comment: Why do you think that it will wait for something? `find_elements_by_id` doesn't wait, but returns list of all elements with specified `id` (or empty list) immediately

Comment: It would wait if there is no element exist with the specified locator, If there is atleast one element exist, then it would quickly return the count but if there is no element exists, then it would wait for element to exist to the given implicit wait time

Comment: No. In case there are no elements `find_elements_by_id` returns empty list

Comment: Given 10 seconds of implicit wait and then check it out whether it waits or not. It would surely wait. It doesn't wait if you haven't given the implicit wait.

Comment: I agree with you that there wouldn't any error if there is no element like we met with error if you use find_element but it would wait If we set implicit wait.

Comment: I see nothing about implicit wait in the question... Do you see that OP mentioned something about Implicit wait? Note that in case Implicit wait + `find_element_by_id` we will also wait for element, so I don't think that OP should use Implicit wait in this current case

Comment: Yes find_element waits for element and in the same way find_elements wait for the elements too. If he doesn't include implicit wait, then it wouldn't be problem, agreed. But you simply can't assume that he is not using implicit wait.

Comment: Anyway, even if OP uses Implicitwait, `if driver.find_elements_by_id('smc')` will not raise an error as `if driver.find_element_by_id('sdc')` will do

Comment: Yes, it would not but it would not let the status immediately. And that's not expected when we inquire the status of the element.

Comment: That's why OP should NOT use Implicit Wait. I did not advice to do this, OP told nothing about this, so we can assume OP will not use it... OK?

Comment: Okay no problem.

Comment: Thanks you two for your help! I have two questions here. 1. why "find_element" could not work? 2, If I use the implicitwait after the first "find_elements", will it affect the remaining "find_elements" ?

Comment: 1. This is how `find_element` and `find_elements` work: first one should return element or NoSuchElementException, second- list of elements or empty list. 2. If `driver.implicitly_wait(timeout)` executed once it will affect all the other code lines...

Comment: @Andersson Thank you for your answer! May I have one more question? On what circumstance, will chromedriver exit when the code is running?  I enter the page1, then execute a verification function, then a func1(while true: try...except..). I can complete the verification function without any problems. Then chromedriver.exe exits..

Comment: If you want to force chromedriver to close after you made all required verifications you can call `driver.quit()`

Comment: @Andersson Sorry if I did not specify.. I mean the code crashed with chromedriver.exe exitsted itself after completing the verficication function....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your scenario and the problem... You can submit new question regarding this new issue if current is solved

Comment: @Andersson I will first see if I can resolve by myself. Anyway, thank you again!

Comment: @Winnie-c ChromeDriver automatically closes the browser, you don't have to close the browser like you do in Firefox.

Comment: @Andersson  I raised a new question following this one. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854268/selenium-chromedriver-exe-exited-automatically-with-function-in-the-if) ....Would you please also check as you have already known what I want.....Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can write you own method to check if element exists, Java example:

```
public boolean isExist(WebDriver driver, By locator) {
    try {
        return driver.findElement(locator) != null;
    } catch (WebDriverException | ElementNotFound elementNotFound) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In python maybe it will look like(not sure!) this:

```
def isExist(driver, by, locator):
    try:
        return driver.find_element(by, locator) is None
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
```

Or

```
def isExist(driver, id):
    try:
        return driver.find_element_by_id(locator) is None
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
```

and use it:

```
if isExist(driver, "smc")
   fun1()
```

Comment: Thanks! I may have figured out!

Answer (score 0):

As per your question to decide the *three options* and run the next step accordinglyyou can use the following solution :

- You can write a *function* as `test_me()` which will take an argument as the `id` of the element and provide the status as follows:

  ```
  def test_me(myString):
      try:
          driver.find_element_by_id(myString)
          print("Exits")
      except NoSuchElementException:
          print("Doesn't exit")
  ```
- Now you can call the *function* `test_me()` from anywhere within your code as follows:

  ```
  test_me("smc")
  #or
  test_me("editPage")
  #
  test_me("cas2_ilecell")
  ```