# Selenium: Chromedriver.exe exited automatically with function in the if

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I changed my code with the help of the [how to decide if the element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838719/selenium-error-comes-using-if-to-decide-whether-an-element-exists-or-not)...
When I add the function test() under the ("casa2_ilecell"), After I enter this page, a window will pop up and shows that "chromedriver.exe exited automatically" and if you click the "confirm" button, the browser will terminate.

I insert the test function directly before the if sentence. And it can work without questions. Any ideas please?

Code:

```
def test():   ##A loop to calculate the page loding time
    while True:
        try:
            navigationStart = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.navigationStart")
            # domComplete = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.domComplete")
            loadEvent = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing. loadEventEnd")
            onloadPerformance = loadEvent - navigationStart
            time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            print(onloadPerformance)
            driver.refresh()
        except TimeoutException:
            print("It took too long")
            break
        except not driver.find_elements_by_id("cas2_ilecell"):
            print("The page does not exist")
            break

    # driver.quit()


u = getpass.getuser()

# # initialize Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\%s\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data' % (u))

# chrome_driver_binary="E:\MyDownloads\Download\chromedriver.exe"
source = "https://na66.salesforce.com/5000y00001SgXm0?srPos=0&srKp=500"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get(source)
try:
    driver.find_element_by_id("Login").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Don't find the login button")

#test()  ##If I run the function here, and delete the bellowing code, it will be no problem

if driver.find_elements_by_id("smc"):
    verificationcode()
    ##If the verification code is not correct()
    ########
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"cas2_ilecell")))
    test()
elif driver.find_elements_by_id("editPage"):
    print("Too much")
    driver.quit()
elif driver.find_elements_by_id("cas2_ilecell"):
    print("Welcome")
    test()     **##Tried to disable the function, and it can complete the code without problem. When the function is added, even the "welcome" could not be printed.**
else:
    print("Ops")
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: `except not driver.find_elements_by_id("cas2_ilecell")` this is incorrect syntax. You can catch only classes that inherits from `BaseException`. Try to replace with `if not driver.find_elements_by_id("cas2_ilecell")`

Comment: @Andersson I deleted that exception. It seems that it is not root cause... Still get "chromedriver.exe" stop working.